# Android rectangle gradient centerX not working

Tags: java, android, drawable

I'm trying to make a gradient effect for my `ListView` item background.
So I created a new drawable XML with the following content:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:centerX="10%"
    android:startColor="#FF0000"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:angle="0" />
```

But it seems that the `centerX` attribute isn't working since the `centerX` point is still at 50%. And if I change `centerX` to any other value no changes are made.
I also tried to use decimal numbers (0.1) but still no success.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a linear gradient the `centerX` attribute corresponds to the position of the `centerColor` (which you did not define).

Something like this should work:

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FF0000"
    android:centerColor="#FF0000"
    android:centerX="10%"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF" />
```